# chrome extension onHeadersReceived listener redirect with wrong location

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension to process pdf from web. because of that, I need to redirect the pdf source url to my extension url. such as,

```
chrome-extension://extension_id/assets/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/3.1.x/django.pdf
```

My background script is:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    httpPdfListener, {
        urls: ['https://*/*', 'http://*/*'],
        types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']
    }, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
)

function httpPdfListener({ responseHeaders, url }) {
    if (!responseHeaders) {
        return
    }

    const contentTypeHeader = responseHeaders.find(
        ({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === 'content-type'
    )
    if (contentTypeHeader && contentTypeHeader.value) {
        const contentType = contentTypeHeader.value.toLowerCase()
        if (
            contentType.endsWith('pdf') ||
            (contentType === 'application/octet-stream' && url.endsWith('.pdf'))
        ) {
            const redirectUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL(
                `assets/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`
            )
            
            return { redirectUrl };
        }
    }
}
```

When I get `https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/3.1.x/django.pdf`, the response header is:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, max-age=7200
cf-cache-status: EXPIRED
cf-ray: 60c5884a4860190c-SIN
cf-request-id: 076f53826a0000190cce09d000000001
content-length: 154
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 04 Jan 2021 14:08:35 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Mon, 04 Jan 2021 16:08:35 GMT
location: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django/3.1.x/django.pdf
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, max-age=7200
cf-cache-status: EXPIRED
cf-ray: 60c5884a4860190c-SIN
cf-request-id: 076f53826a0000190cce09d000000001
content-length: 154
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 04 Jan 2021 14:08:35 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Mon, 04 Jan 2021 16:08:35 GMT
location: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django/3.1.x/django.pdf
server: cloudflare
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-backend: web000028
x-served: Nginx
```

the `location` should be `chrome-extension://extension_id/assets/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/3.1.x/django.pdf`, but got `https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django/3.1.x/django.pdf`. what's more, the `redirectUrl` was correct when logged in devtools.

Comment: I see `content-type` is `text-html` so your code won't process it.

Comment: I think I should have processed this request because the response page has changed.

Comment: Just in case: yes, you should have but you didn't because the `if` condition never matched.

Comment: If the `if` condition is not met, the response page should remain the same, but in my case the response page is not the original page.

Comment: Thing is, your `if` condition will never match - assuming the info you provided in the question is true - so there's no reason to expect this code to work at all.

Comment: Why do you say that, the conditions can definitely be met. The `console.log` inside is executed.

Comment: There's no console.log in the code so it looks like the info in the question is not true. Note that `text/html` will never match the `if` that checks `contentType`.

Comment: This response header is the response header after code processing, which is not the same as the `responseHeaders` in the code.

Comment: Then it should be removed from the question or you need to describe what these headers are and maybe add the original headers because as it stands the question is unanswerable. Assuming the real code actually runs and you verified it by placing console.log right before returning `redirectUrl` (or by using a breakpoint in debugger), the only explanation is that there's another extension that intercepts the request earlier or it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I think it should be, because when I set `redirectUrl` to "https://www.google.com/", It can redirect normally. I will update this post, if I find the problem.

Comment: No, just because it works on a different URL doesn't mean it should work on this one. Another extension may be processing only pdf links. The bug may manifest only on pdf links.

Comment: I tried to disable all other extensions and the problem persists. And when I copy the link and paste it into the browser address bar to open it manually, it can be opened normally.

Comment: Since the question still doesn't contain the info needed to exclude the possibility of incorrect code (the real headers that the extension sees aren't shown here), there's nothing new I can say - the only other explanation is a bug in Chrome...